# jquery pushing object items to array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ho can I convert this :

```
var arr = [{"1":["34"]},{"2":["32","31","30"]},{"3":["29","28","27","26"]}]
```

to this:

```
{"1":["34"],"2":["32","31","30"],"3":["29","28","27","26"]}
```

Is there a function in jQuery to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

```js
var array = [{ 1: ["34"] }, { 2: ["32", "31", "30"] }, { 3: ["29", "28", "27", "26"] }],
    object = Object.assign({}, ...array);
    
console.log(object)
```

Comment: why there is ...array  (3 dots) is this the synthax ?

Comment: it it the spread syntax, which takes an array and use it as parameters for the function call.

Comment: you _can_ avoid the spread: `Object.assign.apply({}, [{ 1: ["34"] }, { 2: ["32", "31", "30"] }, { 3: ["29", "28", "27", "26"] }]);` of course, not too many places will have `Object.assign()` but not spread support, but a partial poly-fill of assign() can support the above in ES5.

Comment: jshint does not accept the spread syntax I get message: 'Unexpected token: punc (.)',

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do it in "old style":

```
var src = [{"1":["34"]},{"2":["32","31","30"]},
      {"3":["29","28","27","26"]}], trg = {};

src.forEach((e)=>{for(var p in e) trg[p]=e[p];});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 arr.reduce((obj, arrayElem) => Object.assign(obj, arrayElem), {})
```

Just reduce the array by assigning all Objects together. Or:

```
 Object.assign({}, ...arr)
```